# How to use postgres ::date with knex.js

Tags: node.js, postgresql, date, knex.js

I have a column of type `timestamp`. I need to select all records by given date. In sql it's something like:

```
select * from "table" where "date"::date = '2015-08-22';
```

I tried following:

```
db('table').select().where('date::date', '=', date);
```

But this throws error

> error: select * from "table" where "date::date" = $1 - column "date::date" does not exist

because knex place quotes wrong.

Is there any way to perform such query? Or I should use `whereRaw`?

Comment: I hope that column name `date` was used only as an example. It is really bad to use this column name In real application.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For dialect specific functionality like this you often need to use [`knex.raw`](http://knexjs.org/#Raw). In this case you can the shorthand, [`whereRaw`](http://knexjs.org/#Builder-whereRaw).

```
db('table').select().where(knex.raw('??::date = ?', ['date', date]));
db('table').select().whereRaw('??::date = ?', ['date', date]);
```

Comment: You are a god sir

Answer (score 3):

`::someType` is a postgres way of using standard `cast(something as sometype)`. You can try to find this `cast` in your framework.

Other option is to use `date_trunc('day',date) = to_date('2015-08-22', 'YYYY-MM-DD')` or `date_trunc('day',date) = '2015-08-22'`

Comment: How does one implement those functions in `knex.js`?

Answer (score -1):

You got the type casting idea reversed, hence the issue: Data casting is to be applied to values, not to column names.

i.e. change to this:

```
select * from "table" where "date" = '2015-08-22'::date;
```

And you can still use a date/time function on column `date`, if you need to extract a part from it, or to match to another type.

Comment: Can you provide an example of how this would be implemented in `knex.js`?

Comment: @kuanb sorry, I don't use knex, only query-based frameworks, like [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Comment: You can also cast columns to `::date`. For a TIMESTAMP column, this will have the effect of ignoring the time part for any comparisons.